# unexpected value changing in javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<body>
<script src="http://www.cse.msu.edu/~zhangh40/w/wgl.js"></script>
<script>

    var li = [[1,3,4,5],[1,2,3,1],[3,5,6,2]];
    var m = r4dxy(0.1);
    var i = 0;
    li[i] = m.ope(li[0]);
    document.write(i);

</script>
```

Why the variable 'i' in above code would be changed to 5?

Answer (score 3):

It is a bug in the http://www.cse.msu.edu/~zhangh40/w/wgl.js file which is creating a global variable `i` in the below loop in `matrixMul` method

```
for (i = 1; i <= this.r * other.c; i++) {
```

which should have been

```
for (var i = 1; i <= this.r * other.c; i++) {
```

In non strict mode, when you assign a variable which is not declared using `var` in a scope, the variable will get created in the global scope.

In your case your variable `i` is in the global space which is initialized with value `0` but when you call `m.ope` it internally calls `matrixMul` which is overriding the value of `i` in the global scope affecting your variable.

---

The function has other undeclared variable also like `a` and `b`

```
function matrixMul(other) {
    var i, a, b;
    if (this.c != other.r)
        return false;
    li = [];
    for (i = 1; i <= this.r * other.c; i++) {
        a = (i % other.c == 0) ? other.c : (i % other.c);
        b = Math.floor((i - 1) / other.c + 1);
        sum = 0;
        for (j = 1; j <= other.r; j++)
            sum += (this.at(b, j) * other.at(j, a));
        li.push(sum);
    }
    return new matrix(li, this.r, other.c);
}
```

Comment: Also, it needs `var` for the variables `a`, `b`, `li`, and `sum` as well.

Answer (score 1):

Because the code in http://www.cse.msu.edu/~zhangh40/w/wgl.js is improperly written.

That code has a function that says:

```
function matrixMul(other){
    if(this.c != other.r)
        return false;
    li = [];
    for(i=1;i<=this.r*other.c;i++){
        a = (i%other.c==0)?other.c:(i%other.c);
        b = Math.floor((i-1)/other.c+1);
        sum = 0;
        for(j=1;j<=other.r;j++)
            sum+=(this.at(b,j)*other.at(j,a));
        li.push(sum);
    }
    return new matrix(li,this.r,other.c);
}
```

Note how that function uses the variable `i` **without ever using the `var` statement**. That means that it messes with the global variable `i`, and affects surrounding code. That method needs to use `var` to refer to all of its internal variables (not just `i`, but also `a`, `b`, `li`, and `sum`)